# How to get deleted device list from Apple developer account?

Tags: ios

While reseting the device list, mistakenly I have selected those device which I suppose to remove and removed those devices which I suppose to keep.
Now how can I get that device list which I have removed from developer account?

Answer (score 1):

Contact Apple Care about this. From a recent question I understood that they keep this information for a *very* long time.

They had a track for me of an iMac DV which I don't own anymore since…
(imagine the spinning beach balloon starting here).